# Switching from Unity to Gnome -- lost top bar programs

Tags: unity, gnome

In Unity, I have some programs that sit on my top bar for applications like Dropbox and Weather Indicator.

In Gnome Shell, these disappear from the top bar and instead only appear on the bottom of the Gnome shell. How do I get them back to the ever-present top bar?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Gnome puts your notifications on the bottom. Maybe you can find a shell extension at http://extensions.gnome.org that would satisfy your needs.